# Elucidate on tantra Sadhna?

Tags: moksha, tantra, guru, brahmins, gayatri-mantra

I have heard of different (tantric?) sadhnas like Vetal Sadhna,Pisach Sadhna,Bhuvaneshwari Sadhna,Hamjaad Sadhna etc..where the beings invoked through the said Sadhna will perform certain tasks/fulfill certain desires of the sadhak/provide him/her with wealth/act as an advisor and a helper to the Sadhak.

I have also heard a story of an aspiring  sadhak who wanted to learn and perform the Karnapishachini Sadhna(in hope of wealth),and hence approached the guru Narayan Dutt Srimaliji.Srimaliji promptly refused to teach a **vammargi** sadhna,but upon the to be sadhak’s insistence,Srimaliji eventually taught him the Sadhna.

The sadhak recounts that because of him practising such a Sadhna,he had lost his Brahmin status,and the right to chant the Gayatri mantra or to involve in the worship of any deity.

There is also an account of how he killed the Pishachini using a Vetaal’s help.

Please elucidate,and share your views (with scriptural evidence,if possible),on the paragraphs above and also explain why the guru refused to teach it initially;thank you.

Here is the video that describes how he got the Sadhna: https://youtu.be/CTYTNf3zP4I

Here is the playlist of the channel that describes him killing the Pishachini: https://m.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLh_uTl4W6Tr5xzaCAHS-uovqF_JLlrSpk

Edit:
My questions are :

**Why did the guru refuse the sadhak initially?**

**Why did he lose his status as a Brahmin,the right to chant the Gayatri Mantra**

**Comment on whether the above mentioned sadhnas are recommended for a spiritual aspirant,or will they block him from attaining moksha ,and please provide scriptural evidence**

Comment: @Proxy Thank you!“..slightly then..?”Death,permanent insanity are two outcomes;so I’ve heard.If the sadhak is aware enough,then he wouldn’t be distracted from moksha,whilst being powerful,right?”don’t like worship of gods”,as in,do they leave/kill the sadhak if he involves in worshiping gods?I have not heard of such a thing.Also,these are called “tantric” sadhnas,yet they do not put emphasis on moksha ,can they still be called “tantric “?I ain’t doing these sadhnas,just makes me curious .Plus,there are other sadhnas that benefit humanity,but are extremely rare(don’t know lot about them,though)

Comment: @Proxy”because of their very nature”:would you please explain that further?Also,how long will it take for someone to actually answer my question?I wanted someone to answer with all the scriptural quotes..Thank you for taking your time though.

Comment: Why did he lose his status as a Brahmin,the right to chant the Gayatri Mantra  --- how did he know that he has lost his Brahmin status and lost the right to chant Gayatri mantra? Is it mentioned in the video itself?@Amethyst

Comment: @Rickross I listened to the video, at 6:00 to 6.15, the narrator mentions that to obtain the siddhi of karnapishachini one has to abandon the tarpan, gayatri japa, sandhya etc. Not only during the sadhana but even in future- (possibly life long).

Comment: oh ok ... @Proxy